# How to retrieve an int value rather than a boolean from a TINYINT(1) column?

Tags: .net, mysql

I have a MySQL column specified as:

```
`type` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

The intent of the column is to store an integer value not to exceed 127 as there are not expected to be more than a very few object "types."

I've stored '2' in the field for one of my rows.

Using [SqlYog](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/), a simple `SELECT type FROM table` yields the proper result, 2.

However, using the Connector/Net 6.1.2 (admittedly it's a bit out of date, as the current version is 6.5.4), the following happens:

```
var Temp = Reader["type"].GetType(); // equals "Boolean"
```

This type of column *is* usually used for Boolean values, but in this case I want to get the integer value. The following fails to yield the expected result:

```
int i = Reader.GetInt32("type"); // equals 1 (should be 2)
```

What's the proper way to get int values from a TINYINT(1) column using Connector/Net in a .NET app?

*This is using MySQL version 5.5.16*

Comment: You are right; `TINYINT` is usually used for booleans. I would suggest to just use a regular `INTEGER` type field, storage space can't be *that* expensive. ;)

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT CAST(type AS SIGNED) AS type FROM table` ?

Comment: Storage isn't a problem; but my concern was more for speed/performance. If I know a particular value will never exceed a limit, I try to size the column appropriately. (Which is why not all of my int columns are `BIGINT`. :) ) Perhaps I should just use `SMALLINT` and call it a day, but I wanted to find out more technical background on this case.

Comment: @Eugen I haven't - I'm in the process of designing the table so have the option to specify the column type in a way that will make unusual queries unnecessary. I'm just being (overly?) curious about this as I came across it.

Comment: WHat happens if you use `Reader.GetValue()` or `Reader.GetSByte()` instead of `Reader.GetInt32()` ?

Comment: @ypercube: It appears that `.GetSByte()` works. `.GetValue()` did not, however, it still returned a boolean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer for the Connector's confusion may be this part from [MySQL docs; Numeric Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html):

> As of MySQL 5.0.3, a `BIT` data type is available for storing bit-field values. (Before 5.0.3, **MySQL interprets `BIT` as `TINYINT(1)`**.) ...

or (even more probable) this part from [Numeric Type Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html):

> **`BOOL, BOOLEAN`**
>
> **These types are synonyms for `TINYINT(1)`**. A value of zero is considered false. Nonzero values are considered true ...

Comment: I think this pretty solidly answers the "why" of the question. It explains why the Connector's results are different from Sqlyog's. It also pretty much tells me to use TINYINT(2) (or a greater 'display width') as the workaround.

Answer (score 5):

Put that in your connection string to use tinyint as number

TreatTinyAsBoolean=false

Comment: Official documentation of this can be found at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-net-connection-options.html Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

One solution I've found is to simply change the column type to `UNSIGNED`:

```
`type` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

This has the following effect:

```
var Temp = Reader["type"].GetType(); // equals "Byte"
```

Which does retrieve the proper result (2) upon calling .GetInt32().

However if for some reason you wanted to store values from -127 to 127 (using it as a signed TINYINT) this solution doesn't work.

---

Another solution is to change the column type to TINYINT(2):

```
`type` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

This gives:

```
var Temp = Reader["type"].GetType(); // equals "SByte"
```

Also yielding the proper result (2).

However this brings into question the purpose of the number after TINYINT (i.e. `TINYINT(#)`). Isn't it for ["optionally specifying the display width"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html)? Maybe someone can shed more light on this point.