# Retrieving a MySql Tinyint(1) data type into a .Net application

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database

I am using MySQL Connector/Net v.6.6.5 to pull data into my .Net application from a remote MySql database.  One of the columns being read from the MySql database is a tinyint(1) data type containing values from 0-5.  The problem is that the connector reads this column type as a bool (true/false) instead of an int.  Thus, everything greater than 0 is returned as a one.  This is a big problem.  I don't have the luxury of altering the database column.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve an int value rather than a boolean from a TINYINT(1) column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728994/how-to-retrieve-an-int-value-rather-than-a-boolean-from-a-tinyint1-column)

Comment: @RohitVats - this question is different - OP doesn't have the ability to change to Tinyint(2)

Comment: what's the problem with retrieving bool and converting to integer based on its value?

Comment: Can you do a cast to int in your MySql query?

Comment: Did you try `YourReader.GetInt32(Columnindex);` ?

Comment: @RohitVats - You are correct.

Comment: @Axarydax - Converting a bool to int will only provide values from 0-1. The tinyint(1) column contains data from 0-5 so that does not work.

Comment: @DeMama - Have not tried that.

Comment: This was my solution, hopefully it will help someone in my situation in the future. My original query was:


<code>SELECT tinyint_column FROM table_with_a_tinyint<code>

Using MySql.data.dll driver returns either TRUE or FALSE

By changing my query to this:
 
'code'SELECT (tinyint_column+0) FROM table_with_a_tinyint'code'

I was able to get the correct 0-5 numbers. A hack, but it works!

Comment: Can you post the answer below so that it can help someone in future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the solution I ended up using. My original query was:

```
SELECT tinyint_column FROM table_with_a_tinyint
```

Using MySql.data.dll driver returns either TRUE or FALSE, which can easily be converted to a 1 or 0. But the data being read from the tinyint(1) column contained 0-5. I was able to extract the correct values by editing my query to below:

```
SELECT (tinyint_column+0) FROM table_with_a_tinyint
```

This yielded the correct values (0-5) from the MySql tinyint column. Hopefully it will help someone in the same situation in the future.