# Tinyint mapped with boolean fields in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

I'm trying to map the 'tinyint' with 'boolean' field, but its giving me below issue. This issue is comming with local database only with live database its working fine. I don't understand where is issue, might be its region issue. I'm using dapper for mapping purpose. 
 Please help me if you have any idea, below is copied exception.

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.DataException' occurred
>   in DAL.dll Additional information: Error parsing column 15 (IsBold=1 -
>   SByte).

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: I don't know about dapper but you may want to check the last answer here re TreatTinyAsBoolean : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728994/how-to-retrieve-an-int-value-rather-than-a-boolean-from-a-tinyint1-column

Comment: Boolean is mapped to the Bit type in C# and Tiny Int  to Byte, why not use the correct mapping, it will work like a breeze, with no grey areas

Comment: Hmmm... looking at the code, it should be using the `OpCodes.Conv_Ovf_I4` conversion in this case. Let me check whether that is valid...

Comment: I also tried Bit for mapping with Boolean, but it's not working. @MrinalKamboj

Comment: When connection pointing to Live database things work fine. There is only version difference Live(5.1.73) and Local Database version(5.6.17)

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, that sounds like a bug. We handle many similar conversions.

The raw IL (using `OpCodes.Conv_Ovf_I4`) works fine in a local test; I'm slightly hampered here, because I don't have mysql locally, and all the servers I *do* have: only have unsigned tinyint. Is there any inner exception here, or something else I can work with? But: this is probably a question for the [github issues list](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/issues).

Comment: I have used (OpCodes.Conv_Ovf_I4) in below statement but not working, throwing exception "Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program"

il.BeginCatchBlock(typeof(Exception)); 
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, typeof(SqlMapper).GetMethod("ThrowDataException"), null);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_1); 
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_Ovf_I4);
            il.EndExceptionBlock();

Answer (score 0):

You can make a quick extension to the datatype tinyint as so:

```
public static class IntExtensions
{
   public static bool AsBool(this int value)
  {
     return value != 0;
  }
}
```

Then you can use this anywhere in your code as such:

```
IsBold == 1.AsBool()
```

Comment: Appreciate quick response, but issue is coming when dapper trying to map the table fields with class properties.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed MySql community edition (`@@version` reports `5.7.11-log`). The following works fine on 1.50-beta9.

```
[FactMySql]
public void SO36303462_Tinyint_Bools()
{
    using (var conn = GetMySqlConnection(true, true, true))
    {
        try { conn.Execute("drop table SO36303462_Test"); } catch { }
        conn.Execute("create table SO36303462_Test (Id int not null, IsBold tinyint not null);");
        conn.Execute("insert SO36303462_Test (Id, IsBold) values (1,1);");
        conn.Execute("insert SO36303462_Test (Id, IsBold) values (2,0);");
        conn.Execute("insert SO36303462_Test (Id, IsBold) values (3,1);");

        var rows = conn.Query<SO36303462>("select * from SO36303462_Test").ToDictionary(x => x.Id);
        rows.Count.IsEqualTo(3);
        rows[1].IsBold.IsTrue();
        rows[2].IsBold.IsFalse();
        rows[3].IsBold.IsTrue();
    }
}
class SO36303462
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsBold { get; set; }
}
```

Please try 1.50-beta9. If that doesn't fix it, please help me to reproduce a failing test.

Comment: I even tried using `IsBold tinyint signed not null` - it still worked fine

Comment: Your are right Marc Gravell, I also changed the data type, its working fine.

Comment: @GurpreetSingh so... is there a remaining problem? or did it just fix itself? or was it 1.50-beta9 that fixed it?

Comment: Nothing remained. Issue fixed.

Comment: I saw different behavior when "select *" was used versus "select Id, IsBold" - enumerating the columns (as you would in a complex join) seems to cause the SByte exception.